# Customization of login screen is not working in Keycloak application?

Tags: keycloak

provide configuration for customization of login page.

`https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes`

Tried the above tutorial but its not working.
Do i need any permission for customization?

Comment: It's taking the default login css theme instead of the theme which i created.

Comment: You don't need any special permissions. But you have to select the theme in the Admin console in *Realm Settings* / *Themes*.

Comment: I have selected mytheme in realm settings but still its taking the default theme.

Comment: Without seeing any code and the structure of the generated .jar file, it will be difficult to diagnose your problem. You'll have to provide much more information.

Comment: Login\keycloak-4.5.0.Final\themes\keycloak\login\resources\css\login

Comment: parent=base
import=common/keycloak
styles=node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly.css node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly-additions.css lib/zocial/zocial.css css/login.css

Comment: It's my theme.properties under login besides resources foder

Comment: Hi, please post your whole theme implementation..

Comment: i'm able to apply myTheme  to master realm and it automatically getting applied to all other realms.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change the logo, so I tried following the official tutorial, but it did not change. After all, I found that we should add few html lines containing the css class (resources/*.css) to display the logo instead of the default text. Steps below:

- Select you Realm
- Go to Realms Settings
- Tab General

  - Fill the HTML Display Name field (by default it is blank) with the content having class `kc-logo-text` (`login.css` related) or your custom class (you can see the Master realm did it) in order to make the logo appeared.
  - Save
- Tab Themes

  - Select your custom theme
  - Save

```
// For example:
HTML Display Name: <div class="kc-logo-text"><span>Keycloak</span></div>
```

Solution derived after I read https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-September/019320.html